# Memory allocation keeps increasing while querying sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, memory-management

```
+ (BOOL) isExistingTicket:(NSString *)TicketID{
int numrows=0;

sqlite3 *database;

NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *sqlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select count(*) from tickets WHERE  ticket_id = '%@' LIMIT 1",TicketID];
    sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;


    int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlString UTF8String], -1, &selectStatement, NULL);


    if (returnValue == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            numrows= sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, 0);
        }
    }


    sqlite3_finalize(selectStatement);
}
else
    sqlite3_close(database);

if (numrows > 0) {
    return YES;
}else{
    return NO;
}
```

}

Data set of around 200 comparing is using this query in my app. App memory usage keeps increasing when this function is called several times. It consumes more than 25Mb and does not decrease after that. Why is this happening? Can you suggest any optimizations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code closes the database only when the `sqlite3_open` call failed.

Move the `sqlite3_close` call into the first branch of the `if`.